# Adding a splash screen after clicking the 2nd exit button

Tags: javascript, html, css, splash-screen

At the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/wust7gdy/

After the curtain goes up, the exit button appears.

How do I add a splash screen after clicking the **2nd** exit button?

Currently, I have a splash screen added after the **1st** exit button is clicked.

I want to add another splash screen after the **2nd** exit button is clicked.

How do I do that?

I don't know how to have this working in the code.

All I am doing is replicating `.splash-screen2`

I can't seem to figure out how to do this in the code.

```
.splash-screen3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    Background-color: green;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
  }

  .splash-screen3.hide {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 3s;
    cursor: default;
  }
```

html:

```
<div class="splash-screen3">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="container2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/z5MMJnv.png" alt="Image 1">
      <div>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5u16syR.png" alt="Image 2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ygTtvme.png" alt="Image 3">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QziKNDW.png" alt="Image 4">
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8Jf8LLc.png" alt="Image 5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How the code should work:

**1st** exit button is clicked:

[image]

Then you see this:

[image]

That disappears and then you see the videos:

[image]

Scroll down and click **2nd** exit button:

[image]

Then you should see **2nd** splash screen:

[image]

That disappears and then you see the videos:

[image]

```js
/*global YT */
/*jslint browser:true */
/*jslint devel: true */

window.onload = function() {

  const splashScreen = document.querySelector('.splash-screen');
  splashScreen.classList.add('hide');

  const panel = document.querySelector('.panel');
  panel.classList.add('slide');

  const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');

  // Add event listener to splashScreen
  splashScreen.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    // Unhide .wrap after splash-screen transition ends
    wrap.classList.remove('hide');
  });

  panel.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    //  panel.style.display = 'none';
    const closeButton = document.querySelector('.exitInitial');
    //blogPager.classList.remove('hide');
    closeButton.classList.add('visible');
  });
}

addYoutubeScriptTagToHTML();

const myModal = document.querySelector("#myModal");
const containerA = document.querySelector('.containerA');
const containerB = document.querySelector('.containerB');
const splashScreen2 = document.querySelector('.splash-screen2');

const closeModal = document.querySelector(".exitInitial");
closeModal.addEventListener("click", modalClickHandler);


const players = [];

splashScreen2.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
    splashScreen2.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
});


/*
 * EVENT HANDLERS
 */

// This function is automatically called by the YT Player API
// after downloading.
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  // Load default video
  const defaultVideo = {
    class: ".playInitial",
    options: {
      playerVars: {
        loop: 1
      }
    }
  };
  const parent = document.querySelector(defaultVideo.class).parentElement;
  createPlayer(parent, defaultVideo.options);
}

function modalClickHandler() {
  if (players[0]) {
    players[0].destroy();
    // you have to remove the player from our global list now
    players.shift(); // this removes first item
  }

  console.log("hit");
  myModal.classList.remove("open");
  //containerA.classList.remove('hide'); // Show containerA
  containerB.classList.add('hide'); // Hide containerB
  splashScreen2.classList.add('hide');

  const videosToAddAfterModalClick = [{
      class: ".playa",
      options: {

      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playb",
      options: {
        videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playc",
      options: {
        videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playd",
      options: {
        videoId: "CHahce95B1g",
        playerVars: {
          start: "50"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playe",
      options: {
        playerVars: {
          playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
        }
      }
    },
  ];
  videosToAddAfterModalClick.forEach(function(video) {
    const parent = document.querySelector(video.class).parentElement;
    createPlayer(parent, video.options);
  });
}
//const splashScreen3 = document.querySelector('.splash-screen3');
const exitButton = document.querySelector('.exit');

/*splashScreen3.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  splashScreen3.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
});*/

exitButton.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);

function exitClickHandler() {
  players.forEach(function(player) {
    player.destroy();
  });

  containerA.classList.add('hide'); // Hide containerA
  containerB.classList.remove('hide'); // Show containerB
  //splashScreen3.classList.add('hide');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 
  const videosToAddAfterExitButtonClick = [{
      class: ".playf",
      options: {

      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playg",
      options: {
        videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playh",
      options: {
        videoId: "CHahce95B1g"
      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playi",
      options: {
        videoId: "CHahce95B1g",
        playerVars: {
          start: "50"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      class: ".playj",
      options: {
        playerVars: {
          playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
        }
      }
    },
  ];
  videosToAddAfterExitButtonClick.forEach(function(video) {
    const parent = document.querySelector(video.class).parentElement;
    createPlayer(parent, video.options);
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  const player = event.target;
  player.setVolume(100);

  if (player === players[0]) {

  }
}

function shufflePlaylist(player) {
  player.setShuffle(true);
  player.playVideoAt(0);
  player.stopVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  const eventPlayer = event.target;
  if (eventPlayer !== players[0]) {
    if (event.data === 1) {
      players.forEach(function pauseOtherVideos(player) {
        const hasIframe = player.getIframe();
        const isDifferentPlayer = player !== eventPlayer;
        const isPlaying = player.getPlayerState() === 1;
        if (hasIframe && isDifferentPlayer && isPlaying) {
          player.pauseVideo();
          console.log("pause");
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
  let id = video.dataset.id;
  if (id.startsWith("PL")) {
    // Check if id starts with 'PL' which is common in YouTube playlist ids
    playerOptions.playerVars = playerOptions.playerVars || {};
    playerOptions.playerVars.listType = "playlist";
    playerOptions.playerVars.list = id;
  } else {
    playerOptions.videoId = id;
  }
  playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
  playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
  playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
  playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;

  players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerOptions));
}


function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions) {
  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 0,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  };

  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1, opts2) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
  const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);

  addPlayer(video, options); // Call addPlayer here
}

function addYoutubeScriptTagToHTML() {
  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}
```

```css
  /*:root {
    --color-a: #1155cc;
    --color-b: transparent;
    --color-c: #1155cc;
    --color-d: transparent;
  }*/

  svg {
    --color-a: red;
    --color-b: black;
    --color-c: red;
    --color-d: black;
  }

  .modal {
    display: none;
  }




  body:has(.modal.open) {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .modal.open {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: black;

  }



  .modal-content {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 640px;
    border: 21px solid;
    border-radius: 3.2px;
    border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
    position: relative;

    padding: 1px;
  }

  .modal-content::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #0059dd;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  :root {
    --wide: 8.8%;
    --angle1: 0;
    --angle2: -90;
  }

  .panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background:
      repeating-linear-gradient(calc(var(--angle1) * 1deg), #ffffff00 0, #ffffff00 var(--wide), #ffffff1a calc(var(--wide) + 1px), #0000004d calc(var(--wide) + 2px), #ffffff00 calc(var(--wide) + 5px)), repeating-linear-gradient(calc(calc(var(--angle2) + 90) * 1deg), #ffffff00 0, #ffffff00 var(--wide), #ffffff1a calc(var(--wide) + 1px), #0000004d calc(var(--wide) + 2px), #ffffff00 calc(var(--wide) + 5px));
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #191919;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition: 8s;
  }

  /*body:has(.splash-screen.hide[style]) .modal-content .panel {
    transition-delay: 4s;
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
  }*/

  .panel.slide {
    transition-delay: 2s;
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
  }

  /*
  
  

All that is needed
body:has(.splash-screen.hide[style]) .modal-content .panel {
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% - 1px));
}

window.onload = function() {
  const splashScreen = document.querySelector('.splash-screen');
  splashScreen.classList.add('hide');
  splashScreen.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    splashScreen.style.display = 'none';
  });
};*/

  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
    background: #121212;
    padding: 50px 8px;
  }

  .containerA {
    background-color: Red;

  }

  .container,
  .container5 {
    max-width: 642px;
    margin: 15px auto 30px;
    padding: 15px;
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);*/
    border: 1px solid #0059dd;
    border-radius: 0;

    background: linear-gradient(45deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
        transparent 7.5px,
        transparent 10px),
      linear-gradient(-45deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
        transparent 7.5px,
        transparent 10px);
    background-size: 10px 10px;

  }

  .containerB {
    background-color: blue;

  }

  .ratio-keeper {
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  /*.ratio-keeper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }*/

  .video-frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .exitInitial {
    transform: translatey(100%);
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /*margin: auto auto 0;*/
    pointer-events: initial;
    top: auto;
    bottom: -1px;
    margin: auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*margin: 10px auto 0;*/
    width: 47px;
    height: 47px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*margin: auto;*/
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .exitInitial.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
  }


  .exitInitial::before,
  .exitInitial::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: red;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .exitInitial::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }











  .splash-screen {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    /* Set transition duration to 1 seconds */
    pointer-events: none;
    /*dissable mouse clicking */
    cursor: default;
  }

  .splash-screen.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 2s;
    /* Add a delay of 1 seconds before the opacity changes to 0 */
    pointer-events: none;
    /* Re-enable mouse clicking after 1 seconds */
    cursor: default;
  }


  .splash-screen2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    Background-color: black;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
    opacity: 1;
    /* Set transition duration to 1 seconds */
   
    /*dissable mouse clicking */
    cursor: default;
  }

  .splash-screen2.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 3s;
    /* Add a delay of 1 seconds before the opacity changes to 0 */
  
    /* Re-enable mouse clicking after 1 seconds */
    cursor: default;
  }



  .splash-screen3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    Background-color: green;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="165" height="165" viewBox="0 0 165 165"><rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 0px; fill: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="72.5" y="72.5" width="25" height="25" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="62.5" y="62.5" width="45" height="45" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="52.5" y="52.5" width="65" height="65" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="42.5" y="42.5" width="85" height="85" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="32.5" y="32.5" width="105" height="105" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="22.5" y="22.5" width="125" height="125" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="12.5" y="12.5" width="145" height="145" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /><rect x="2.5" y="2.5" width="165" height="165" style="fill: none; stroke-width: 5px; stroke: rgb(17, 85, 204);" /></svg>');
    opacity: 1;
    /* Set transition duration to 1 seconds */
    pointer-events: none;
    /*dissable mouse clicking */
    cursor: default;

  }

  .splash-screen3.hide {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 3s;
    /* Add a delay of 1 seconds before the opacity changes to 0 */
    pointer-events: none;
    /* Re-enable mouse clicking after 1 seconds */
    cursor: default;

  }







  .inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;

    z-index: 2;
  }


  .container2 {
    max-width: 360px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  .container2 div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .container2 img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: auto;
  }




  .blog-pager2 {
    max-width: 674px;
    height: 52px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #0059dd;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
        transparent 7.5px,
        transparent 10px),
      linear-gradient(-45deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7px,
        rgb(113, 121, 126) 7.5px,
        transparent 7.5px,
        transparent 10px);
    background-size: 10px 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .exit {
    position: relative;
    width: 47px;
    height: 47px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*margin: auto;*/
  }



  .exit::before,
  .exit::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: red;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }

  .exit::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }


  .footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
    background: #121212;
    height: 59px;
  }

  .footer {
    margin: 0 -8px
  }

  .wrap.hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .containerB.hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .containerA.hide {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal open">
  <div class="modal-content">
   
    <button class="exitInitial" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>
  
    <div class="ratio-keeper">
      <div class="wrap hide remove">
        <div class="video video-frame remove wrap" data-id="PL6KcpeEiGPpxSF3yIJSsNSOZGb4hBXhrN"></div>
      </div>
        <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="playInitial remove"></div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end modal -->

<div class="outer-container">
<div class="containerA ">
<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio-keeper " >
    <div class="video video-frame " data-id="PL6KcpeEiGPpxSF3yIJSsNSOZGb4hBXhrN"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playa"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame"  data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playb"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playc"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playd"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playe" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
</div>
<div class="blog-pager2 ">
        <button class="exit" type="button" title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></button>
  
</div>

</div>


<div class="containerB hide">
<div class="container5">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playf"></div>
</div>
<div class="container5">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame"  data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playg"></div>
</div>
<div class="container5">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playh"></div>
</div>
<div class="container5">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playi"></div>
</div>
<div class="container5">
  <div class="ratio-keeper">
    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="playj" data-id="AxLxnN6z0Og"></div>
</div><div class="blog-pager2   remove">
   <a title="Exit" aria-label="Close"></a>
  
</div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
</div>


<div class="splash-screen">
  <div class="circle">
    <svg class="box" width="170" height="170" viewBox="0 0 170 170">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="170" height="170" fill="var(--color-a)"/>
      <rect x="5" y="5" width="160" height="160" fill="var(--color-b)" />
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150" fill="var(--color-c)"/>
      <rect x="15" y="15" width="140" height="140" fill="var(--color-d)" />
      <rect x="20" y="20" width="130" height="130" fill="var(--color-a)"/>
      <rect x="25" y="25" width="120" height="120" fill="var(--color-b)" />
      <rect x="30" y="30" width="110" height="110" fill="var(--color-c)" />
      <rect x="35" y="35" width="100" height="100" fill="var(--color-d)" />
      <rect x="40" y="40" width="90" height="90" fill="var(--color-a)" />
      <rect x="45" y="45" width="80" height="80" fill="var(--color-b)" />
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="70" height="70" fill="var(--color-c)" />
      <rect x="55" y="55" width="60" height="60" fill="var(--color-d)" />
      <rect x="60" y="60" width="50" height="50" fill="var(--color-a)" />
      <rect x="65" y="65" width="40" height="40" fill="var(--color-b)" />
      <rect x="70" y="70" width="30" height="30" fill="var(--color-c)" />
      <rect x="75" y="75" width="20" height="20" fill="var(--color-d)" />
      <rect x="80" y="80" width="10" height="10" fill="var(--color-a)" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="splash-screen2">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="container2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/z5MMJnv.png" alt="Image 1">
      <div>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5u16syR.png" alt="Image 2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ygTtvme.png" alt="Image 3">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QziKNDW.png" alt="Image 4">
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8Jf8LLc.png" alt="Image 5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--<div class="splash-screen3">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="container2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/z5MMJnv.png" alt="Image 1">
      <div>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5u16syR.png" alt="Image 2">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ygTtvme.png" alt="Image 3">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/QziKNDW.png" alt="Image 4">
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8Jf8LLc.png" alt="Image 5">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this with they way your code works is to do the following:

First, add `hide` class to `splash-screen3`, like:

```
<div class="splash-screen3 hide">
```

Then you need to remove `pointer-events: none;` from `.splash-screen3` CSS:

```
...
    opacity: 1;
    /* Set transition duration to 1 seconds */
    pointer-events: none; /* REMOVE THIS */
    /*dissable mouse clicking */
    cursor: default;
  }
...
```

Then add this splash-screen3 selector:

```
...
const splashScreen2 = document.querySelector('.splash-screen2');
const splashScreen3 = document.querySelector('.splash-screen3'); // ADD THIS
```

Then add this event listener on splash-screen3 to remove pointer events when the transition has ended:

```
...
splashScreen3.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
    splashScreen3.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
});
...
```

Finally, add these lines at the end of `exitClickHandler`:

```
...
function exitClickHandler() {
...
  splashScreen3.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
  splashScreen3.classList.remove('hide');
  splashScreen3.offsetWidth = splashScreen3.offsetWidth;
  splashScreen3.classList.add('hide');
}
...
```

The first line is to reenable the `pointer-events` CSS, then we remove the `hide` class to show the `splashScreen3` again, then we set the offsetWidth as a dummy so that a reflow is triggered, then finally we add `hide` class again to the `splashScreen3` to hide it again.

[Here is the forked jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/740Lr1mw/)

Comment: Do you think there is a way for it to work without setTimeout in the code?

Comment: @EveNinnall updated, now without `setTimeout` at all, please recheck the jsfiddle

Comment: What if I was adding a sliding curtain instead of a splashscreen? Seen here? https://jsfiddle.net/7mcxwhvo/ Replicating the same sliding curtain effect after clicking the first exit button Where you see it split in half. How would I apply that to occur after clicking the 2nd exit button also? https://i.imgur.com/JPQOGQy.png

Comment: I attempted, I tried to figure it out in the code but I wasn't successful.

Comment: @EveNinnall here https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/wu3ad1h6/, if you need an explanation, just post another question and i'll answer there

Comment: How would you change or modify the code here? At the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ndfwymg7/

Each holds different images:

<div class="slide panel-left"><div class="slide panel-right">

<div class="slide curtain-left hide"><div class="slide curtain-right hide">

Comment: Doing this did not work in the code:   const curtainLeft = document.querySelector('.curtain-left');
  const curtainRight = document.querySelector('.curtain-right'); / Maybe more things would need to be done so it will work? / I changed the classes from one to the other: https://jsfiddle.net/r40u76h8/

Comment: Panels left/right have theses as all 5 images: https://i.imgur.com/2NcDQ1H.png

Curtains left/right holds different images.

Comment: @EveNinnall can you reformulate the question? I don't understand, or maybe post another question, and i'll answer it there

Comment: 5 pictues are assigned to this: <div class="slide panel-left"> <div class="slide panel-right"> Which appears after clicking the 1st exit button.

After clicking the 2nd exit button, this one should be unhidden:

5 different pictues are assigned to this: <div class="slide curtain-left hide"> <div class="slide curtain-right hide">

How do I do that in here? https://jsfiddle.net/r40u76h8/

Comment: The code here: https://jsfiddle.net/sunepr5b/

These 5 images appear after clicking both exit buttons.

https://i.imgur.com/Vmb9B8P.png

If I want the images shown to be different after clicking the 2nd exit button, I would need to add a 2nd sliding curtain.

Which is in there:

<div class="slide curtain-left hide">

<div class="slide curtain-right hide"> / it would need to be unhidden after clicking the 2nd exit button.

Comment: At the code here: How do I have the 2nd curtain split in half? https://jsfiddle.net/cxnz3q04/ Click on the 2nd exit button and it is not moving.

Comment: @EveNinnall here https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/r3zvwnup/